# What is faster when comparing image vs javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, html

I'm wondering if there is a big difference when loading graphics made in pure javascript or using a large image.

As reference i made this example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hustlerinc/gxxFb/). From a performance perspective what is best, drawImage using a png image or drawing it using javascript?

Comment: Did you benchmark both versions?

Comment: Use jsperf to get this answer

Comment: No I didn't try any benchmarks, can I do it without having a webhost?

Comment: Write a benchmark on http://jsperf.com/ to get your answer (pretty scene, btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex images, rendering will be slow, because javascript is slow itself. 
For hundreds of small images, using a img tag will probably be very fast.

The only way to kill perfomance is by having a "javascript that run very long", because is blocking (and that can be avoided with some worker/consumer pattern),  or having gigantic images with alpha transparency.

Future versions of Chrome and Opera will have a profiler for CSS/rendering, that will tell you exactly how much and what is taking more time to render.